# Merge Replication Failing

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I have 3 databases replicating using merge replication.  All servers are running SQL Server 2008. The replication had been running fine for years. About a month ago one of the subscriber databases failed and had to be rebuilt. After it was rebuilt, I reattached it to replication. Replication worked fine for about 12 hours and then started to fail with the error:

---

I ran the profiler on the Publisher and this is what I see:

```
exec sp_executesql N'EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_sqlagent_log_jobhistory @job_id = @P1, @step_id = @P2, @sql_message_id = @P3, @sql_severity = @P4, @run_status = @P5, @run_date = @P6, @run_time = @P7, @run_duration = @P8, @operator_id_emailed = @P9, @operator_id_netsent = @P10, @operator_id_paged = @P11, @retries_attempted = @P12, @session_id = @P13, @message = @P14',N'@P1 uniqueidentifier,@P2 int,@P3 int,@P4 int,@P5 int,@P6 int,@P7 int,@P8 int,@P9 int,@P10 int,@P11 int,@P12 int,@P13 int,@P14 nvarchar(4000)','8DB8503F-0332-41D6-A90A-1F5E88275761',2,0,0,4,20150907,144600,107,0,0,0,0,151,N'
2015-09-07 21:46:00.146 Copyright (c) 2008 Microsoft Corporation
2015-09-07 21:46:00.146 Microsoft SQL Server Replication Agent: replmerg
2015-09-07 21:46:00.146 
2015-09-07 21:46:00.146 The timestamps prepended to the output lines are expressed in terms of UTC time.
2015-09-07 21:46:00.146 User-specified agent parameter values:
        -Publisher PublisherServer
        -PublisherDB PublisherDatabase
        -Publication Publisher_Pub
        -Subscriber SubScriptionServer\SQLExpress
        -SubscriberDB SubscriptionDatabase
        -Distributor PublisherServer
        -DistributorSecurityMode 1
        -XJOBID 0x3F50B88D3203D641A90A1F5E88275761
        -XJOBNAME PUBLISHERSERVER-PublisherDatabase-Publisher_Pub-SubscriptionServer\SQLExpres-14
        -XSTEPID 2
        -XSUBSYSTEM Merge
        -XSERVER PublisherServer
        -XCMDLINE 0
        -XCancelEventHandle 0000000000000864
        -XParentProcessHandle 0000000000000740
2015-09-07 21:46:00.171 Connecting to Distributor ''INLANDTARPSQL''
2015-09-07 21:46:00.277 Initializing
2015-09-07 21:46:00.279 Connecting to Publisher ''INLANDTARPSQL''
2015-09-07 21:46:02.886 Connecting to Subscriber ''ITL-JER-ERP\SQLExpress''
2015-09-07 21:46:03.017 Retrieving publication information
2015-09-07 21:46:03.099 Retrieving subscription information.
2015-09-07 21:46:57.089 Uploading data changes to the Publisher
2015-09-07 21:46:58.003 Set last sent generation at the Subscriber with value 18601
2015-09-07 21:46:58.239 Set last received generation at the Publisher with value 18601
2015-09-07 21:46:58.383 No data needed to be merged.
2015-09-07 21:46:58.488 Downloading data changes to the Subscriber
2015-09-07 21:47:02.050 Enumerating deletes in all articles
2015-09-07 21:47:02.169 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''Addresses''
2015-09-07 21:47:02.497 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''CustRef''
2015-09-07 21:47:02.891 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''JobSheets''
2015-09-07 21:47:03.233 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''Notes''
2015-09-07 21:47:03.698 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''OtherPay''
2015-09-07 21:47:04.417 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''RecordChanges''
2015-09-07 21:47:04.773 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''Stacks''
2015-09-07 21:47:05.150 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''StacksToTarps''
2015-09-07 21:47:05.474 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''StackSub''
2015-09-07 21:47:05.808 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''TarpInspections''
2015-09-07 21:47:06.332 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''TarpInventory''
2015-09-07 21:47:06.694 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''TimeClock''
2015-09-07 21:47:07.001 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''TimeClock2''
2015-09-07 21:47:07.311 Enumerating inserts and updates in article ''Customers''
2015-09-07 21:47:07.666 No data needed to be merged.
2015-09-07 21:47:07.840 The merge process could not enumerate changes at the ''Publisher''. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
2015-09-07 21:47:07.958 Category:NULL
Source:  Merge Replication Provider
Number:  -2147200999
Message: The merge process could not enumerate changes at the ''Publisher''. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
```

'

If reinitialize the subscription, it will work again for about 12 hours before failing again.

The other subscriber continues to run without any errors.

Any help on what could be causing the problem or tips on how to get to the underlying error would be appreciated.

**Here is the log with -OutputVerboseLevel set to 3, it doesn't seem to give any more information:**

```
2015-09-08 02:39:01.108 OLE DB Distributor: CompanySQL
            DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
            Version: 10.00.5538
            catalog name: 
            user name: dbo
            API conformance: 0
            SQL conformance: 0
            transaction capable: 1
            read only: F
            identifier quote char: "
            non_nullable_columns: 0
            owner usage: 15
            max table name len: 128
            max column name len: 128
            need long data len: 
            max columns in table: 1000
            max columns in index: 16
            max char literal len: 131072
            max statement len: 131072
            max row size: 131072
2015-09-08 02:39:01.110 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sp_MSgetversion }
2015-09-08 02:39:01.115 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sp_helpdistpublisher (N'CompanySQL') }
2015-09-08 02:39:01.118 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sp_MShelp_repl_agent (N'CompanySQL', N'Company', N'Company_Pub', N'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress', N'Company', 1)}
2015-09-08 02:39:01.119 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': select datasource, srvid from master..sysservers where upper(srvname) = upper(N'CompanySQL')
2015-09-08 02:39:01.120 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sp_MShelp_merge_agentid (0,N'Company',N'Company_Pub',null,N'Company',90,N'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress')}
2015-09-08 02:39:01.122 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sp_MShelp_profile (14, 4, N'')}
2015-09-08 02:39:01.124 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:39:01.125 Connecting to OLE DB Publisher at datasource: 'CompanySQL', location: '', catalog: 'Company', providerstring: '' using provider 'SQLNCLI10'
2015-09-08 02:39:01.126 Initializing
2015-09-08 02:39:01.128 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:39:01.131 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:39:01.132 Connecting to Publisher 'CompanySQL'
2015-09-08 02:39:01.133 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:39:01.137 OLE DB Publisher: CompanySQL
            DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
            Version: 10.00.5538
            catalog name: Company
            user name: dbo
            API conformance: 0
            SQL conformance: 0
            transaction capable: 1
            read only: F
            identifier quote char: "
            non_nullable_columns: 0
            owner usage: 15
            max table name len: 128
            max column name len: 128
            need long data len: 
            max columns in table: 1000
            max columns in index: 16
            max char literal len: 131072
            max statement len: 131072
            max row size: 131072
2015-09-08 02:39:01.139 OLE DB Publisher 'CompanySQL': set nocount on declare @dbname sysname select @dbname = db_name() declare @collation nvarchar(255) select @collation = convert(nvarchar(255), databasepropertyex(@dbname, N'COLLATION')) select collationproperty(@collation, N'CODEPAGE') as 'CodePage', collationproperty(@collation, N'LCID') as 'LCID', collationproperty(@collation, N'COMPARISONSTYLE') as 'ComparisonStyle',cast(case when convert (int,databasepropertyex (@dbname,'comparisonstyle')) & 0x1 = 0x1 then 0 else 1 end as bit) as DB_CaseSensitive,cast(case when convert (int,serverproperty ('comparisonstyle')) & 0x1 = 0x1 then 0 else 1 end as bit) as Server_CaseSensitive set nocount off
2015-09-08 02:39:01.141 OLE DB Publisher 'CompanySQL': {call sp_MSgetversion }
2015-09-08 02:39:01.148 Connecting to OLE DB Publisher at datasource: 'CompanySQL', location: '', catalog: 'Company', providerstring: '' using provider 'SQLNCLI10'
2015-09-08 02:39:01.154 OLE DB Publisher: CompanySQL
            DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
            Version: 10.00.5538
            catalog name: Company
            user name: dbo
            API conformance: 0
            SQL conformance: 0
            transaction capable: 1
            read only: F
            identifier quote char: "
            non_nullable_columns: 0
            owner usage: 15
            max table name len: 128
            max column name len: 128
            need long data len: 
            max columns in table: 1000
            max columns in index: 16
            max char literal len: 131072
            max statement len: 131072
            max row size: 131072
2015-09-08 02:39:01.161 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sp_MShelp_repl_agent (N'CompanySQL', N'Company', N'Company_Pub', N'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress', N'Company', 1)}
2015-09-08 02:39:01.163 Connecting to OLE DB Subscriber at datasource: 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress', location: '', catalog: 'Company', providerstring: '' using provider 'SQLNCLI10'
2015-09-08 02:39:04.201 OLE DB Subscriber: COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress
            DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
            Version: 10.00.5538
            catalog name: Company
            user name: dbo
            API conformance: 0
            SQL conformance: 0
            transaction capable: 1
            read only: F
            identifier quote char: "
            non_nullable_columns: 0
            owner usage: 15
            max table name len: 128
            max column name len: 128
            need long data len: 
            max columns in table: 1000
            max columns in index: 16
            max char literal len: 131072
            max statement len: 131072
            max row size: 131072
2015-09-08 02:39:06.998 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sp_MSgetversion }
2015-09-08 02:39:08.157 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': set nocount on declare @dbname sysname select @dbname = db_name() declare @collation nvarchar(255) select @collation = convert(nvarchar(255), databasepropertyex(@dbname, N'COLLATION')) select collationproperty(@collation, N'CODEPAGE') as 'CodePage', collationproperty(@collation, N'LCID') as 'LCID', collationproperty(@collation, N'COMPARISONSTYLE') as 'ComparisonStyle',cast(case when convert (int,databasepropertyex (@dbname,'comparisonstyle')) & 0x1 = 0x1 then 0 else 1 end as bit) as DB_CaseSensitive,cast(case when convert (int,serverproperty ('comparisonstyle')) & 0x1 = 0x1 then 0 else 1 end as bit) as Server_CaseSensitive set nocount off
2015-09-08 02:39:08.474 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:39:08.474 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:39:08.475 Connecting to Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress'
2015-09-08 02:39:08.476 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:39:08.996 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:39:08.996 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:39:08.998 Retrieving publication information
2015-09-08 02:39:08.999 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:39:09.260 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:39:09.261 Retrieving subscription information.
2015-09-08 02:39:09.262 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:27.586 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:27.879 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:27.880 Uploading data changes to the Publisher
2015-09-08 02:41:27.881 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:29.787 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:30.054 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:30.056 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:30.057 Set last sent generation at the Subscriber with value 18601
2015-09-08 02:41:30.058 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:30.507 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:30.508 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:30.510 Set last received generation at the Publisher with value 18601
2015-09-08 02:41:30.514 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:30.764 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:30.764 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:30.767 No data needed to be merged.
2015-09-08 02:41:30.768 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:31.215 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:31.216 Downloading data changes to the Subscriber
2015-09-08 02:41:31.217 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:34.654 Connecting to OLE DB Publisher at datasource: 'CompanySQL', location: '', catalog: 'Company', providerstring: '' using provider 'SQLNCLI10'
2015-09-08 02:41:34.662 OLE DB Publisher: CompanySQL
            DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
            Version: 10.00.5538
            catalog name: Company
            user name: dbo
            API conformance: 0
            SQL conformance: 0
            transaction capable: 1
            read only: F
            identifier quote char: "
            non_nullable_columns: 0
            owner usage: 15
            max table name len: 128
            max column name len: 128
            need long data len: 
            max columns in table: 1000
            max columns in index: 16
            max char literal len: 131072
            max statement len: 131072
            max row size: 131072
2015-09-08 02:41:34.664 Connecting to OLE DB Subscriber at datasource: 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress', location: '', catalog: 'Company', providerstring: '' using provider 'SQLNCLI10'
2015-09-08 02:41:36.473 OLE DB Subscriber: COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress
            DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
            Version: 10.00.5538
            catalog name: Company
            user name: dbo
            API conformance: 0
            SQL conformance: 0
            transaction capable: 1
            read only: F
            identifier quote char: "
            non_nullable_columns: 0
            owner usage: 15
            max table name len: 128
            max column name len: 128
            need long data len: 
            max columns in table: 1000
            max columns in index: 16
            max char literal len: 131072
            max statement len: 131072
            max row size: 131072
2015-09-08 02:41:37.932 Connecting to OLE DB Publisher at datasource: 'CompanySQL', location: '', catalog: 'Company', providerstring: '' using provider 'SQLNCLI10'
2015-09-08 02:41:37.939 OLE DB Publisher: CompanySQL
            DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
            Version: 10.00.5538
            catalog name: Company
            user name: dbo
            API conformance: 0
            SQL conformance: 0
            transaction capable: 1
            read only: F
            identifier quote char: "
            non_nullable_columns: 0
            owner usage: 15
            max table name len: 128
            max column name len: 128
            need long data len: 
            max columns in table: 1000
            max columns in index: 16
            max char literal len: 131072
            max statement len: 131072
            max row size: 131072
2015-09-08 02:41:37.940 Connecting to OLE DB Subscriber at datasource: 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress', location: '', catalog: 'Company', providerstring: '' using provider 'SQLNCLI10'
2015-09-08 02:41:40.258 OLE DB Subscriber: COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress
            DBMS: Microsoft SQL Server
            Version: 10.00.5538
            catalog name: Company
            user name: dbo
            API conformance: 0
            SQL conformance: 0
            transaction capable: 1
            read only: F
            identifier quote char: "
            non_nullable_columns: 0
            owner usage: 15
            max table name len: 128
            max column name len: 128
            need long data len: 
            max columns in table: 1000
            max columns in index: 16
            max char literal len: 131072
            max statement len: 131072
            max row size: 131072
2015-09-08 02:41:41.809 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:42.200 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:42.200 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:42.206 Enumerating deletes in all articles (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:42.206 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:42.650 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:42.651 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'Addresses' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:42.651 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:43.474 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:43.946 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:43.947 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'CustRef' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:43.948 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:44.810 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:45.299 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:45.300 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'JobSheets' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:45.301 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:46.247 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:46.695 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:46.696 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'Notes' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:46.697 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:47.714 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:47.999 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:48.000 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'OtherPay' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:48.001 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:48.948 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:49.462 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:49.463 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'RecordChanges' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:49.465 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:50.475 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:50.875 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:50.877 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'Stacks' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:50.878 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:51.836 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:52.253 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:52.257 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'StacksToTarps' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:52.260 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:53.069 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:53.656 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:53.657 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'StackSub' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:53.658 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:54.638 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:55.017 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:55.018 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'TarpInspections' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:55.019 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:55.991 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:56.499 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:56.502 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'TarpInventory' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:56.507 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:57.447 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:58.016 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:58.016 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'TimeClock' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:58.017 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:59.161 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:41:59.803 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:41:59.804 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'TimeClock2' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:41:59.805 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:42:01.790 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:42:02.336 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:42:02.337 Enumerating inserts and updates in article 'Customers' (generation batch 1)
2015-09-08 02:42:02.337 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:42:02.932 The merge process could not enumerate changes at the 'Publisher'. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
2015-09-08 02:42:02.938 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:42:03.435 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:42:03.437 No data needed to be merged.
2015-09-08 02:42:03.438 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:42:03.461 OLE DB Subscriber 'COMP-JER-ERP\SQLExpress': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:42:04.018 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:42:04.019 The merge process could not enumerate changes at the 'Publisher'. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
2015-09-08 02:42:04.020 OLE DB Distributor 'CompanySQL': {call sys.sp_MSadd_merge_history90 (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}
2015-09-08 02:42:04.480 Percent Complete: 0
2015-09-08 02:42:04.480 Category:NULL
Source:  Merge Replication Provider
Number:  -2147200999
Message: The merge process could not enumerate changes at the 'Publisher'. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write.
2015-09-08 02:42:04.481 The Merge Agent was unable to update information about the last synchronization at the Subscriber. Ensure that the subscription exists at the Subscriber, and restart the Merge Agent. 
2015-09-08 02:42:04.483 The merge process was unable to update last synchronization information at the Publisher.
2015-09-08 02:42:04.485 Disconnecting from OLE DB Publisher 'CompanySQL'
```

...

Comment: "When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write."

Comment: Are you using a filter on the publication?

Comment: No filtering is being used on the publication.